# Iterate and erase elments from std::set

Tags: c++, iterator, set, erase

I have a `std::set` and I need to erase similar adjacent elements:

```
DnaSet::const_iterator next = dna_list.begin();
DnaSet::const_iterator actual = next;
++next;

while(next != dna_list.end()) // cycle over pairs, dna_list is the set
{
    if (similar(*actual, *next))
    {
        Dna dna_temp(*actual);  // copy constructor
        dna_list.erase(actual); // erase the old one
        do
        {
           dna_temp.mutate(); // change dna_temp
        } while(!dna_list.insert(dna_temp).second);  // insert dna_temp
    }
    ++actual;
    ++next;
}
```

Sometimes the program can't exit from the main loop. I think the problem happens when I erase the last element in the `dna_list`. What's the correct way to do this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `actual = next` rather than `++actual`.

Once you erase `actual`, it is an invalid iterator, so `++actual` will behave strangely. `next` should remain intact, so assigning `actual` to `next` should work.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to create a comparison functor that uses the `similar()` predicate. Then all you need to do is construct the set with that comparison functor and you're done. The set itself will see two similar elements as identical and will only let the first one in.

```
struct lt_different {
    bool operator()(int a, int b) {
        return a < b && !similar(a, b);
    }

private:
    bool similar(int a, int b)
    {
        // TODO:when are two elements similar?
        const int EPSILON = 2;
        return abs(a - b) < EPSILON;
    }
};

// ...
set<int> o;  // fill this set with your data

// copy your data to a new set that rejects similar elements
set<int,lt_different> s(o.begin(), o.end(), lt_different());
```

You can work with set `s`: insert elements, remove elements, modify elements -- and the set itself will make sure no two similar elements exist in the set.

That said, you can also write an algorithm yourself, if only for an alternative choice. Take a look at `std::adjacent_find()` from `<algorithm>`. It will find the first occurrence of  two consecutive identical elements; hold on to that position. With that found, find the first element from that point that is different from these elements. You end up with two iterators that denote a range of consecutive, similar elements. You can use the set's `erase()` method to remove them, as it has an overload that takes two iterators.

Lather, rinse, repeat for the entire set.

Comment: How can I implement your first idea? I need to implement `operator==` for the elements of the set? I can't do it, because the concept of similar is different from the concept of equal, and I need both.

Maybe is there a way to tell to `std::set` to use a particular function (different to `operator==`) to decide if two element are duplicates?

Comment: I updated the answer with example code. Yes, all it takes is passing the set's constructor a compare function of your own.